# Filmic color management and masks

Tags: compositing-nodes, masking, filmic-blender

I recently had the problem of having to mask (rotoscope) some footage in the movie clip editor and render out some elements to put in there.
For rendering those 3D elements, I wanted to use the filmic preset, but this gave me the problem that my masks when used in the compositor via the Input - Mask node weren't #FFFFFF anymore (as set in the mask editor), but a darker shade of white, which makes them a tad transparent.
Is there a way to prevent this (except turning their brightness up again via more nodes)?

Comment: Could you post some screenshots of how you're using the masks? Filmic is applied at the end of the composite chain and shouldn't affect individual mask operations within the compositor

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use filmic and output mask with absolute color values](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/92868/use-filmic-and-output-mask-with-absolute-color-values)